# passwordless sudo using ubuntu preseed and packer

Tags: linux, ubuntu, packer

I am attempting to grant passwordless sudo privileges to a user created during Ubuntu 14.04 install. However when the image is created none of the changes related to sudo exist. Here are the relevant parts of the preseed file:

```
# Create Vagrant User
d-i passwd/user-fullname string Vagrant User
d-i passwd/username string vagrant
d-i passwd/user-password password vagrant
d-i passwd/user-password-again password vagrant
d-i user-setup/encrypt-home boolean false
d-i user-setup/allow-password-weak boolean true

# Setup passwordless sudo for vagrant user
d-i preseed/late_command string echo "vagrant   ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL" > /target/etc/sudoers.d/vagrant
d-i preseed/late_command string chmod 0440 /target/etc/sudoers.d/vagrant
```

I have also tried

```
d-i preseed/late_command string in-target echo "vagrant ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL" > /etc/sudoers.d/vagrant
```

When the image finishes /etc/sudoers.d/vagrant will not exist anywhere.

even if I run the commands:

```
d-i preseed/late_command string mkdir /stuff
d-i preseed/late_command string in-target mkdir /stuff
```

the stuff directory will not exist.

I know the commands are being run because I made a typo once and saw an error during install. All other preseed commands seem to be working.

I have read about the in-target directive and that the installer will create a /target that has the finial filesystem however I seem unable to make these work.

using packer I have run a shell script provisioned that does the same echo and that works.

Comment: I think you can only have one `preseed/late_command`, see [here](https://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2012/03/msg01414.html) and [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1977570)

Comment: That worked thank you! if you want to post that as the answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is that a preseed file can only have one `preseed/late_command` section, not multiple.

If you need to execute multiple commands, you can have them as a single late_command separated with `;` e.g.

```
d-i preseed/late_command string \
    in-target cmd1 args ... ; \
    in-target cmd2 args ... ; \
    ...
```

Answer (score 6):

In this particular case, this is what was working for me:

```
d-i preseed/late_command string \
    echo 'vagrant ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL' > /target/etc/sudoers.d/vagrant ; \
    in-target chmod 440 /etc/sudoers.d/vagrant ;
```